# Not getting input text value into php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

on save i am not getting input text value into the .php page. I am getting only file data but not getting post data.
Anyone have any idea, then let me know how eact do mistake from my side
View file as below:

```
$str .='<form name="ipsf_sukanya_form" id="ipsf_sukanya_form"><input type="hidden" name="login_access" id="login_access" value="'.$login_access.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="emp_id" id="emp_id" value="'.$emp_id.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="ipsf_main_id" id="ipsf_main_id" value="'.$main_id.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="'.$action.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="date_of_joining" id="date_of_joining" value="'.$date_of_joining.'">';

else if($action=='add'){
        // for ($j = 0; $j <= $_POST['pro_ext_loc_count2_nsc']; $j++)
        //     { 
        $str .='<table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Investment in Sukanya Samriddhi Scheme-80C</td>
                        <td><input name="sukanya_amt_'.$sukanya.'" type="text" id="sukanya_amt_'.$sukanya.'" size="10" maxlength="14"  class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>
                        <p id="sukanya_amt_error'.$sukanya.'"></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Attachment</td>
                        <td><input name="sukanya_doc_'.$sukanya.'" type="file" id="sukanya_doc_'.$sukanya.'" size="10" maxlength="14"  class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>
                        <p id="sukanya_amt_error'.$sukanya.'"></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                        <div id="table_div_nsc_'.$sukanya.'" style="margin:0;padding:0;"> </div>
                            <div id="ext_loc_count2">
                                <input type="hidden" name="pro_ext_loc_count2_nsc" id="pro_ext_loc_count2_nsc" value="'.$sukanya.'"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table></form>
                ';
            // }
    }
```

Below is the javascript validate function

```
function validate_sukanya(num)
{

     var add = num+1;
     var error = '';
     if($("#sukanya_amt_"+num).val()!= null)
     {
        var sukanya_amt= $('#sukanya_amt_'+num).val();
        console.log(sukanya_amt);
        if(sukanya_amt == '') 
        {

                error += '--Please Enter 3) Contribution to Certain Pension Funds (sec 80CCC) -  Amount for row ';
                // pf_amt.focus();
                $("#sukanya_amt_error"+num).html('<span class="text-danger">Please Enter Amount</span>');
        }
        if(sukanya_amt != "")
        {
            var validNum =  /^([0-9]+)[\.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}$/;
            if (validNum.test(sukanya_amt) == false)
            {
                error += '--Please Enter Valid 3) Contribution to Certain Pension Funds (sec 80CCC) -  Amount for row ';
                    // pf_amt.focus();
                $("#sukanya_amt_error"+num).html('<span class="text-danger">Please Enter Valid Amount</span>');
            }
        }
        if(error == '')
        {
            error += validate_sukanya(add);
            // var sukanya_data = $('#ipsf_sukanya_form').serialize();

            var form = $('#ipsf_sukanya_form')[0];
            // Create an FormData object 
            var sukanya_data = new FormData(form);

            sukanya_data.append('sukanya_file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
            console.log(sukanya_data);


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "../emp_proof_ajax/ajax_insert_sukanya_info.php",
                //data: dataString,
                data : sukanya_data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result20){
                    //alert(result);
                    // console.log("ReS "+result);
            
                    $(".step20").css("display","block");
                    
                    
                    // $("#purchase_property_data").val(result20);
                }
            }); 
            //}
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert(error);
        }
     }
     else
     {
        alert(error);
     }
}
```

and i am trying to fetch both input text and file data into php page but I am getting only file data but not getting input type text data.
php file as follows:

```
<?php 
include('../includes/include.php');
//die("hii");
 // echo '<pre>_POST '; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';exit;
$arr = $_POST['arr'];
// $s = 0;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "<br>";
print_r($_FILES);
die;
 ?>
```

Comment: There's a missing brace before your elseif statement

Comment: Also, though not relevant, you have two paragraph elements with the same id of `sukanya_amt_error'.$sukanya.'`, and as I'm sure you know, each id must be unique on a page.

Comment: Why are you even trying to add files using the `append` method? `new FormData(form)` already serializes the _complete_ form data set for submission, and your file upload fields are part of that form.